# Unbound dns over tls

Tags: dns, ssl, unbound

I have unbound installed and it works just fine (debian testing).
I also have a domain at duckdns.org.


I would like to set DoT on my Android phone as xxxxx.duckdns.org, so i can make all requests go through my server.
What am i suposed to do/install/whatever, to make it work?
Or is this not possible this way?


/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/myconfig.conf

```
server:

  interface: 0.0.0.0
  interface: ::0

  prefetch: yes
  do-not-query-localhost: no

  access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 allow
```

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/myconfig.conf

```
[main]
dns=none
systemd-resolved=false
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver ::1
options trust-ad
```

Answer (score 0):

Hya there!  I am also usign DuckDNS to run my Nextcloud instance and thinking of using it also as a static domain.

With you PiHole/Unbound setup do I understand that you wish to make a VPN to allow your mobile device to use your home network?

If that is the case, you would want to:

1. Link DuckDNS account to your Pi by following their instructions on their web page. This will make sure when your ISP changes your IP address that it will still point to your DuckDNS url.
2. Setup up WireGuard on your Pi and in the setup questions simply have your Pi point to unbound for a DNS resolver (or use a 3rd party serivce)
3. Use the setup process to point to your DuckDNS url to be a static IP address
4. Back on your PI you can then generate a client and it will even create a QR code that you can then use for your mobile devices to be able to connect to (after you install the wireguard app on your device.

Hope this helps!